# ERROR: target not found: yaourt

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, pacman, yaourt

I'm new to arch so any help on this subject is much appreciated. I have been trying to install yaourt on manjaro, but this is the error message I receive.

```
[manjaro@manjaro-pc ~]$ sudo pacman -S yaourt
error: target not found: yaourt
```

Comment: My apologies for the mistake. I am using a fresh install of Manjaro. I began with a system update and upgrade (which i have an error messages);


error: unresolvable package conflicts detected
error: failed to prepare transaction (conflicting dependencies)
:: manjaro-gnome-settings-18.0 and manjaro-gnome-settings-17.0 are in conflict

Comment: regarding your conflicting dependencies, see: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/manjaro-gnome-settings-18-0-and-manjaro-gnome-settings-17-0-are-in-conflict/63701/4

Comment: regarding yaourt: it's slowly dying. You can look into `packer` instead

Comment: use `git clone` then `makepkg`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Yaourt` was removed from the official servers of Arch Linux by serious security problems. Die.

It can no longer -or should not be- download from official repositories, and it's not safe to do it by any other means.

I recommend switching to safer alternatives for `AUR` packages, like `aurman`.

Links of interest:

- [Yaourt is Dead! Use These Alternatives for AUR in Arch Linux](https://itsfoss.com/best-aur-helpers/)
- [Remove yaourt from [archlinuxfr] repo](https://github.com/archlinuxfr/yaourt/issues/209)
- [Arch Wiki - AUR helpers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers)
- [Archero ¡Deja de usar Yaourt! ¡Usa aurman!](https://securityhacklabs.net/forum/distribuciones-gnulinux/archlinux/2018-06-20/archero-deja-de-usar-yaourt-usa-aurman) (Spanish)

**Update with `aurman` installation:**

You can install `aurman` with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /tmp
gpg --recv-key 465022E743D71E39
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/aurman.git
cd aurman
makepkg -si
sudo sed -i '/^#Color/s/^#//' /etc/pacman.conf
aurman -Syu
```

The use of `aurman` is more simple that `yaourt`, and very similar to `pacman`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Finished installing aurman and everything works fine for now.

Comment: This currently gives `==> ERROR: One or more PGP signatures could not be verified!`